# NSAutoreleasepool leaking - Don't understand why?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, multithreading, ios, nsautoreleasepool

I have this code:

```
NSNumber *num;
NSAutoreleasePool *apool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

for (int i=0; i<images_count; i++) {
    num = [NSNumber numberWithInt:images_count];
    [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(loadData:) withObject:num];
}

[apool release];
[num release];
```

and it generates the following error:

2011-06-17 03:10:30.768 CHARLIE[2456:6c03] *** __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x703d0f0 of class __NSArrayI autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking

I don't understand why its leaking, can someone please explain how to fix this?

Thanks a lot,

Jack

Comment: I am not sure why you are creating an autorelease pool in this case. Was there any particular reason for it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a couple of issues with that code.

- The lack of an autorelease pool is probably due to the `loadData:` method running without an autorelease pool.
- The `[num release]` is nonsense.
- Spawning a thread per every iteration of that loop is pretty much guaranteed to be the least performant possible approach to parallelizing image loading.